# Not able to delete JSON object from JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

```
JSON.stringify(jobj);
"[{"aa":"bb"},{"cc":"dd"}]"
```

my Json object is like above one. can any one please explain how to delete `{"cc":"dd"}` from that object.

Comment: Depends how you prefer to target that object. Please provide more details about use case. Also it's not hard to research how to remove an array element. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You could - without any [`JSON`](http://json.org/) - take the array and [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) the last element.

```js
var array = [{ aa: "bb" }, { cc: "dd" }];

array.pop();

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to delete an element from an array, regardless of the type of element, it should be `array.slice(index,1);`

In this specific example, it would be `jobj.slice(1,1);`.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can `parse` the string and use `slice`

```js
var jobj = '[{"aa":"bb"},{"cc":"dd"}]';
console.log(JSON.parse(jobj).slice(0,1));
```

Comment: Huh? Op already started with a valid array. Why stringify just to parse it again?